# How to use cast, DATEADD, DATEDIFF in linq query?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I am using a LINQ query in a C# application.

My SQL query looks like this :

```
select cast(DATEADD(hh, -4, [firstdate]) as DATE) as [Date], COUNT(Name) as 'Total Name',
from Database.dbo.DatabaseName with (nolock)
where DATEDIFF(dd, DATEADD(hh, -4, [firstdate]), getdate()) between 1 and 7
group by cast(DATEADD(hh, -4, [firstdate]) as DATE)
order by cast(DATEADD(hh, -4, [firstdate]) as DATE)
```

But I don't know how to use it in a LINQ Query

Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`SqlFunctions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions) class which has `DateAdd` and `DateDiff` methods, effectively as proxies to the SQL code.

Your LINQ to SQL could probably call `DateAdd` just the once though - if you select it, you can then group by the result of that select, and then select the key and count of each group.